# can't configurate VL53l0x api

Tags: c, configuration, microcontroller, sensors, stm

I'm trying to configure the VL53l0x API, there were multiple errors, but I found a tutorial and it helped me so far with getting rid of them.

But I'm stuck, I've done everything and I have one final error:

> "fatal error: vl53l0x_api.c: No such file or directory".

I have no idea how to solve it; I've added every possible source to the IDE and yet it doesn't work.

Have anyone had this kind of issue before?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should not be `#include`ing a source file. Remove that `#include`.